# Programming in Maple for first time: "Illegal use of formal parameter"

Tags: syntax-error, maple

I keep getting that error. Here's the code (it's for GCD):

```
Euc := proc (a, b) 
if b = 0 then a;
else c := b; 
d := a mod b;
b := d; a := c;
end if;
end proc;
```

I never use Maple because it gives me a headache and the documentation is a nightmare, but this assignment has to be done all in Maple... if I'm having trouble with simple GCD, I don't see me writing RSA and El Gamal by Wednesday :s

**edit:** Fixed it with

```
Euc := proc (a, b) 
if b = 0 then a;
else c := b; 
d := a mod b;
Euc(c,d);
end if;
end proc;
```

But any I'd still like to know what the problem was, in case I have to do something similar again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version attempted to assign to the formal parameters of the procedure. That was the problem.

Suppose you call your original `Euc` and pass in 12 for parameter `a` and 8 for parameter `b`. Inside the body of `Euc`, as it runs in this instance, `a` evaluates to 12 and `a` does not evaluate to a name to which you can make an assignment. When you try and make an assignment to `a` or `b` inside `Euc` then you see that error.